# run a function in javascript with string and object name

Tags: javascript

I saw this question multiple times in different versions,
but nothing helpful for me...

I have this JS objects:

```
var memory = {

    myLoop: function myLoop (action) {
    // do some stuff...
    } }

var messages = {

    myLoop: function myLoop (action) {
    // do some other stuff...
    } }
```

also, i have this array:

```
listOfScreens = ['messages','memory'];
```

And I want to call to myLoop functions from this function:

```
var slider = {
    playScreen: function startScreen(){
        listOfScreens[0].myLoop('play');
        // and next time to call:
        listOfScreens[0].myLoop('play');

    }
}
```

so my question is: how to call to the function myLoop, that live in memory object, from slider object using arrays strings that live in global.

I try a lot but still no success.

Comment: `listOfScreens = [messages, memory]`, or `listOscreens = { messages: messages, ... }`…?

Comment: not really understood. Are you talking about iterator functions ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*

Comment: You’re basically asking for *variable variables*, which is always a bad problem to have. You should put your objects into an array or object as shown above and use them that way, not indirectly through variable names.

Comment: @deceze I disagree strongly. In many cases accessing variable property names of an object is an absolute necessity, in others it's just elegant and convenient.

Comment: @connexo Yes, that’s also valid. Accessing global variables is basically accessing properties of the global object. But if you need to do that, do it explicitly by creating an explicit object with explicit properties, not implicitly through global variables.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using array of string instead of array of objects.

In your code replace below line

```
listOfScreens = ['messages','memory'];
```

With this line,

```
listOfScreens = [messages, memory];
```

Comment: i try also as strings and also as objects names.

when i use with objects names, he looking for "myLoop" function into the array... but the function is not there...

Comment: *from slider object using arrays **strings** that live in global*

Answer (score -1):

Just use the bracket notation to access variable object properties.

```
var slider = {
    playScreen: function startScreen(){
        window[listOfScreens[0]].myLoop('play');
        window[listOfScreens[0]].myLoop('play');
    }
}
```

```js
var memory = {
  myLoop: function myLoop(action) {
    console.log('memory.myLoop called')
  }
}

var messages = {
  myLoop: function myLoop(action) {
    console.log('messages.myLoop called')
  }
}

var listOfScreens = ['messages', 'memory'];

var slider = {
    playScreen: function startScreen(){
        window[listOfScreens[0]].myLoop()
        // and next time to call:
        window[listOfScreens[1]].myLoop()
    }
}

slider.playScreen();
```

Comment: i try now again... i got error again.

Uncaught TypeError: [listOfScreens[0]].myLoop is not a function

Comment: Of course it works as long as `messages` and `memory` are globally scoped, which OP stated.

Comment: Uhm, how about you try it and produce a working sample?

Comment: when i wrote :
messages.myLoop('play');   
it's work fine!

but i want to call the function dynamicly.
any idea how to do this correct?

jest want to call a function from object to do some stuff, and after he finish to call another function to do other stuff...

Comment: @deceze Done. Missed explicitly stating `window`.

Comment: Ok. But since this only works with global variables, it’s a pretty bad solution. (To a bad problem arguably.)

Comment: @deceze I didn't make the question. In other contexts to know how to do this this is an absolute essential knowledge.

Comment: @MendyShechter Re-check my answer and tell me if anything is missing or unclear.

Comment: @deceze i try your example.
not work for me.

can you edit it to run the "window[listOfScreens[0]].myLoop();"
from slider object?

Comment: @MendyShechter Done. Btw, *"not work for me"*  is not a delightful comment. What happens? What error are you getting in the console?

Comment: @deceze Thahnks for you new example.
i try to use with this. here is my error:

mainscreenview.js:249 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'myLoop' of undefined
    at Object.startScreen [as playScreen] (mainscreenview.js:249)
    at Object.dumpMes (mainscreenview.js:388)
    at Object.getMessege (mainscreenview.js:217)
    at Object.<anonymous> (mainscreenview.js:83)
    at u (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)